# is there a way to display a plot using hover template in plotly?

Tags: python, hover, plotly-python

I want to display a plot B on hovering over a point in scatter plot A. Can I do this using plotly?

I tried to enter the pie plot B as a hover template attribute but it does not work. Is plotly the best way to do this or would you suggest another library?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.